# trigger a DSC to run when any VM is added to a resource group

Tags: azure

is there a way a DSC can be automatically applied to any machines in a specific resource group? I want to run a dsc which formats a hard disk to any VM added to a specific resource group. Can this be done via Azure Automation?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible with Azure Automation.

You can use different means to work around this, generally you should "listen" to `Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachine` events and filter out new ones somehow. You can send subscription events to oms\event hub or storage account (afair).